# Charter boat vs. Sea Lanes

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-2

The action Charter boat states that one can move to a city as long as one can draw a route to it by sea.

The draw sea-lane action states that it's only allowed to cross one red line.

So my question is, which of the three interpretations is correct?

1. Charter boat refers to routes as previously defined sea-lanes.
2. Charter boat can move to any city to which there's a complete stretch of water.
3. Charter boat can move to any city to which there's a complete stretch of water, but only crossing one red line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [rulebook](https://images-cdn.zmangames.com/us-east-1/filer_public/38/ec/38ec25b0-821b-4c2e-b925-27c4a4038acd/pandemic_legacy_season_2_rules.pdf) (Page 6) is actually quite clear on this:

> SEA LANES & SEA ROUTES
>
> Locations are connected to each other in the ocean by sea lanes.
>
> Locations directly connected by a sea lane are adjacent.
>
> A series of connected sea lanes is called a sea route.

Given this definition of a sea route, you can only charter a boat from and to a location where you can trace a continuous series of series of sea lanes. So your option 1 is the correct interpretation.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I missed this, but that's the interpretation we used (and hence lost).

Comment: @Þórgnýr Not a problem, it's easy to miss rules in Pandemic Legacy with so much changing all the time. Don't forget to accept an answer if you feel that someone has covered everything.

Comment: Right. Learning.